# How would I store user theme preferences across multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage, themes

I have managed to get a light-dark mode toggle working on my website, but am struggling to figure out how I would implement cookies or localstorage to call upon the user's preferred theme when changing pages on the site.

What I am working with is an external JS file consisting of:

```
const prefersDarkMode = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
const toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
const html = document.querySelector('html');

html.dataset.dark = localStorage.dark || prefersDarkMode.matches;

toggle.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  localStorage.dark = !(html.dataset.dark == 'true');
  html.dataset.dark = localStorage.dark;
});
```

Which is then used in the style sheets by choosing between separate styles with:

```
html[data-dark="false"]{...}
html[data-dark="true"] {...}
```

I am very new to JS, which I am sure shows, and have only gotten to this point with the help of peers. I've done my best to try solutions from other answers here as well as learn more about localstorage and cookies through resources like the Mozilla docs but am struggling. A solution or being pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Edit: To clarify on what I am trying to achieve; I would like it so that user theme preferences are saved and applied to all pages while what I currently have only saves an individual page's user preferences, meaning they would manual have to toggle them each time.

Comment: Hi gitess2 and welcome to SO. Could you specify *what* isn't working and what the expected result should be?

Comment: Thank you! I apologize, I realize I did not clarify past the title. What I have currently works in that it saves each page's preferred theme individually. However, my goal is so that when a user toggles light or dark mode that preference is reflected across all pages.  I currently do not have code trying to complete this as I have had no success. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using localStorage you opperate with `setItem` and `getItem`, you can read more about the examples of how to use localStorage here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#examples.

If you want to get/set localStorage item you would use something like this:

```js
// Creates/sets the localStorage item of "theme" to "dark"
localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark")

// Gets the localStorage item named "theme", and checks if the value is "dark"
const isDarkMode = localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark"
```

One way of implementing this could be something like this:

```js
// DOM elements
const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
const html = document.querySelector("html");

// Check the browser preferred color scheme, and sets the defaultTheme based of that
const prefersDarkMode = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
const defaultTheme = prefersDarkMode ? "dark" : "light";
const preferredTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme")

// Check if the localStorage item is set, if not set it to the default theme
if (!preferredTheme) {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", defaultTheme);
}

// Sets the theme of the site either the preferredTheme or the defaultTheme (based on localStorage)
html.dataset.theme = preferredTheme || defaultTheme;

// Theme toggle handler
toggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Check if the saved theme in localStorage is  "dark"
    const isDarkTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark";
    // Chooses the opposite theme of the current selected one
    const newTheme = isDarkTheme ? "light" : "dark"
    // Changes the theme to the newTheme
    localStorage.setItem("theme", newTheme);
    html.dataset.theme = newTheme;
});
```

You would then need to change your data attributes in the css to check for the `theme` and not `true` or `false` like this:

```css
html[data-theme="light"]{...}
html[data-theme="dark"] {...}
```

Comment: Hello, I appreciate the response! I believe I have implemented your suggestion correctly as I understand it, however the browser's preferred theme seems to be taking priory over the toggle. My browser prefers dark mode and when using light mode with the suggested changes it does not carry over to other pages. Would that be an issue with the 11th and 12th line? Suggestions would be appreciated but regardless I appreciate the help.

Comment: I think I see what was wrong. I forgot to update the localStorage Item when the toggle was clicked. If you test the code again you may see a difference.

Edit: line 11 and 12 should only be ran once, and that is the first time the user visits the site. As this lines sets the localStorage item if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Hello. It appears to be working with your change, however it is still not persisting across multiple pages of the site.

Comment: Hm, I tested this myself and it worked as expected across different pages. Could you check your localStorage in the `application` tab in the dev tools, and see if it is showing there or not? [Application in devtools on chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/localstorage/) There `theme` item should only be on one domain there.

Comment: Looking to the localStorage I can see that the it is at least showing. When using dark theme the local storage on index.html shows (key - value): `dark - false`, `light - true`, `PreferDarkMode - 1` and `theme - dark`. If I change the theme from dark to light the only thing that changes is `theme - light`. The `theme` item is present on all pages however, while the `light` is only on one.

Comment: Are you able to provide the code you have used for saving `dark`, `light` and `PreferDarkMode`? According to your comment here, it seems like the code I proveded for you is working as expected, is your css updated with the correct data attribute proveded `data-theme`?